# Spectrum of the sum and product of two commutative elements in a banach algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a **commutative** unital Banach algebra. We know that for any two elements of $A$ $\sigma(a+b)\subset \sigma(a)+\sigma(b)$ and $\sigma(ab)\subset \sigma(a)\sigma(b)$.

I know that if we consider $2 \times 2$ matrices, then we get examples of a non-commutative unital banach algebra such that $\sigma(a)+\sigma(b)\not\subset \sigma(a+b) $ and $\sigma(a)\sigma(b)\not\subset \sigma(ab)$.

I wonder if there are examples of $a$ and $b$ in a non-unital commutative $A$ such that $\sigma(a)+\sigma(b)\not\subset \sigma(a+b) $ and $\sigma(a)\sigma(b)\not\subset \sigma(ab)$. (I can't think of any at the moment)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $A=\mathbb C^2\oplus C_0(\mathbb R)$. For the sum, you could do
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}\oplus0,\qquad b=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}\oplus0.
$$
Then
$$
\sigma(a)+\sigma(b)=\{-2,0,2\}\not\subset \{0\}=\sigma(a+b).
$$
For the product,
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\oplus0,\qquad b=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\oplus0.
$$
Then
$$
\sigma(a)\sigma(b)=\{0,1\}\not\subset \{0\}=\sigma(ab).
$$

Comment: Isn't the $2 \times 2$ matrices a unital banach algebra?

Comment: Yes, but those examples live in many non-unital Banach algebras; I have edited for your benedit. Note also that you need a unit to define the spectrum.

Comment: Also, isn't $A$ non-commutative in this case? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Basically the same examples work in the commutative case. I have edited to commutative.

Comment: Yes. It's the natural choice for the direct sum.